# How to union two LINQ queries but the second query need have more fields

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need make union between two LINQ queries, but the second query need have more fields that the first. How can I do it?

Example:

```
public static void Dummy()
{
    var query1 = this.Db.Table1.Select(s => new MyObject() { A = s.Field1, B = s.Field2 });

    var query2 = this.Db.Table2.Select(s => new MyObject() { A = s.Field1, B = s.Field2, C = s.Field3 });

    var result = query1.Union(query2);
}
```

When I calls result.ToList(), occurs the following error:

> The type 'MyObject' appears in two structurally incompatible
>   initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be
>   initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same
>   properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the
>   same order.

How Can I resolve this problem?

**Obs.: I can't put the `Field3` in the `query1` (I don't have access to the query one, because this I Can't changed it)**

Comment: Error message is Self Explanatory! If you have already used `Union` in SQL Server etc. then its really easy to understand what it is trying to say.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to put `Field3` in first query but `Union` requires same number of columns and in same order. Specify a dummy value for third column/field `C` like:

```
var query1 = this.Db.Table1.Select(s => new MyObject() 
                        { A = s.Field1, B = s.Field2 , C= ""});
```

Assign `C` whatever is the default value of `Field3`, may be `null` for reference type and `0` for numbers etc.

If you don't have access to it modify `query1` then create a new query using `query1` like:

```
var newQuery = query1.Select(s=> new MyObject() 
                            { A = A, B = B , C= ""});
```

and then use that in `Union`

```
var result = newQuery.Union(query2);
```

Comment: I can't change the query1, because I don't have access to the query.

Comment: @RenatoLeite, you can create a new query on `query1`, I have added some new code, try that.

Comment: I try do it, but not solved the problem, the error persisted :(

Answer (score 2):

As-is, you can't. You can only union 2 sets that have the same structure. If you don't mind modifying `query1`, however:

```
var query1 = this.Db.Table1.Select(s => new MyObject() 
                                        { A = s.Field1, B = s.Field2, C = null });
```

This would allow them to union properly, as they have the same structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, like this:

Create a object devired from MyObject

```
class MyObjectUnion : MyObject{
}
```

So, the method goes like this:

```
public static void Dummy()
{
    var query1 = this.Db.Table1.Select(s => new MyObject() { A = s.Field1, B = s.Field2 });

    var query1modified = this.Db.Table2.Select(s => new MyObjectUnion() { A = s.Field1, B = s.Field2, C = null });

    var query2 = this.Db.Table2.Select(s => new MyObjectUnion() { A = s.Field1, B = s.Field2, C = s.Field3 });

    var result = query1modified.Union(query2);
}
```

It works

Answer (score 0):

Because records in query1 will never have a property "C", and all records in query2 will have a property "C", it is unlikely that a record in query1 will be equivalent to a record in query2.  The only reason for using Union over Concat is to remove duplicates and since you can't have any, you should likely be using Concat instead of Union.

```
public static void Dummy()
{
    var query1 = this.Db.Table1.Select(s => new MyObject() { A = s.Field1, B = s.Field2 });

    var query2 = this.Db.Table2.Select(s => new MyObject() { A = s.Field1, B = s.Field2, C = s.Field3 });

    var result = query1.ToList().Concat(query2);
}
```

There are exceptions, as if you have a custom IEqualityComparer for MyObject that ignores the "C" property, or the default for the "C" property may exist in a record for table2, and you wanted to remove the duplicate, or if there possibly exists duplicates within either query1 or query2 and you wanted them removed then you can still use Concat, but you need to use Distinct before the Concat.

Editted to force query1 to be materialized before concatenation via .ToList()

Double checked with LinqPad, and the following executable had no issues, using a datasource that had both Categories and Cities tables of which were completely different schemas:

```
void Main()
{
    var query1 = Categories.Select(s => new MyObject { A = s.id, B = s.name });

    var query2 = Cities.Select(s =>  new MyObject { A = s.id, B = s.city_name, C = s.location });

    var result = query1.ToList().Concat(query2);
    result.Dump();
}
public class MyObject
{
    public int A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
    public object C {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: @RenatoLeite Depends on the size of the data you are returning and if you are expecting to have to read through all the records or not.  If you aren't expecting to have to read all the records (or read them multiple times),  change .ToList() to .AsEnumerable()